# In a for loop, when are the loop parameters evaluated?

Tags: loops, for-loop, julia

Here's a real beginner question...

In a `for` loop, when are the loop parameters evaluated?

Here, the loop runs forever, so `c` is obviously 'being checked' each time the loop starts:

```
c= [1]
for i in c
   push!(c, i)
   @show c
end
c = [1,1]
c = [1,1,1]
c = [1,1,1,1]
...
```

But this loop is only evaluated once:

```
c= [1]
for i in 1:length(c)
   push!(c, i)
   @show c
end
c = [1,1]
```

This one looks like it evaluates `enumerate(c)` every loop:

```
c= [1]
for (i, _) in enumerate(c)
    push!(c, i)
    @show c
end
c = [1,1]
c = [1,1,1]
c = [1,1,1,1]
...
```

But this loop obviously doesn't:

```
c= [1]
for i in eachindex(c)
    push!(c, i)
    @show c
end
c = [1,1]
```

And this does:

```
c= [1]
foreach(a -> (push!(c, a); @show c), c)
c = [1,1]
c = [1,1,1]
c = [1,1,1,1]
...
```

As I said, it's a real beginner question. But am I missing a general pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the main point is that your various loops are invoking Julia's iterator interface on two different types of object:

- the array object `c` itself
- an `AbstractUnitRange` object (or one of its subtypes)

---

When you loop with `for i in c`, Julia doesn't know how large `c` is. All Julia needs is the current state of iteration (the index it has reached) and what the next index to visit in `c` should be. It can test if it is finished iterating over `c` if this next index will take it out of bounds.

Copying from Julia's [iterator interface](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/interfaces/) documentation, such a loop essentially boils down to:

```
state = start(c)
while !done(c, state)
    (i, state) = next(c, state)
    # body
end
```

If you append to `c` in the body of the loop, there will always be a next index to visit (i.e. `while !done(c, state)` will always be `true`). The array `c` can grow until your memory is full.

The loops using [`enumerate`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a304c557928d9eaa0a28af5fe96327d5da70d14b/base/iterators.jl#L29-Lundefined) and [`foreach`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/61b0efc38588e7e04d593d706fb45b1339aab39d/base/abstractarray.jl#L1660-Lundefined) both depend on the iterator interface to the array `c` in the same way, and so you see similar behaviour when modifying `c` during these loops.

---

On the other hand, the loops using `for i in 1:length(c)` and `for i in eachindex(c)` do not iterate over `c` itself, but different objects supporting the iterator interface.

The key point is that these objects are created *before* iteration begins and they are not affected when modifying `c` in the body of the loop.

In the first case, `length(c)` is computed and then `1:length(c)` is created as an object of `UnitRange` type. In your example it starts at 1 and stops at 1, so we `push!` to `c` only once during iteration.

In the second case, calling `eachindex([1])` returns a `Base.OneTo` object; just like a `UnitRange` object, except guaranteed to start at 1. In your example case `Base.OneTo(1)` is created and start at 1 and stops at 1 too.

Both of these objects are subtypes of `AbstractUnitRange` and ultimately subtypes of `AbstractArray`. The iterator interface allows you to access the values held by these objects in sequence.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Might be worth adding to the official docs... I might get round to making a PR one day... :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Good idea: I think Julia's docs are generally very good but it might be useful to emphasise the differences in the ways of iterating where appropriate.